# 2d coordinate system: Math vs. Screen

Tags: java, computational-geometry, coordinate-systems

We're working on a library that does calculations in 2D space.  However, the 'natural' interpretation of the 2D coordinate system is where increasing Y values represent points that lie higher, while the `awt` coordinates do the reverse.  This reflects in `Rectangle(10,100).maxY()` returning 0, while the mathematician would expect it to return 100.

How can we properly deal with that difference?  Is there another java library to do geometrical calculations?

Comment: I'd stick to manual conversion. You still have to transform, so why not scale the Y axis by a negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try things before asking. The following code prints 100, so there is no problem :)

```
import java.awt.*;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double maxX = new Rectangle(10, 100).getMaxY();
        System.out.println("A::main: maxX = " + maxX);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about both things.  I was confused by the documentation talking about 'upper-left corner' etc... but this does not reflect in the API.

Comment: In 2D graphics programming the y axis usually has the positive direction downwards. Don't worry, after a while it seems quite intuitive :)

Answer (score 1):

I turns out that `maxY` returns 'the biggest y-coordinate`, which is exactly the intuitive behavior.  I was confused: only when actually drawing it to screen the objects have a 'top-left' and a 'bottom-right' are merely conventions when visualizing it.